# Incorrent date when deserializing using Jackson

Tags: java, json, date, jackson

Ive tried everything I know to solve this issue but I am stuck. For some reason I add the date below on the  JSON String and the `Mapper` adds hours to the date. Why is it adding the 18:00:00?

```
   String json = "{\n" + 
        "  \"feature\": {\n" + 
        "    \"due_date\": \"2019-02-25\"\n" + 
        "  }\n" + 
        "}";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
    Wrapper feature = mapper.readValue(json, Wrapper.class);
    Feature sample = feature.getFeature();
    System.out.println(sample.getDueDate());
```

---

```
public class Feature implements Serializable {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = DateAdaptor.class)
    private String dueDate;
    public Date getDueDate() {
        return due_date;
    }
    @JsonProperty("due_date")
    public void setDueDate(Date dueDate) {
        this.due_date = dueDate;
    }
}
```

---

```
    public class Wrapper implements Serializable {
private Feature feature;
public Feature getFeature() {
    return feature;
}
public void setFeature(Feature feature) {
    this.feature = feature;
}
    }
```

---

```
public class DateAdaptor extends StdDeserializer<Date>{

    private SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    public DateAdaptor() {
        this(null);
    }

    protected DateAdaptor(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext context)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String date = jsonparser.getText();
        try {
            return formatter.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

---

`OUTPUT Sun Feb 24 18:00:00 CST 2019`

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: I cant use Java 8. I would love to but we dont have that luxury yet lol

Comment: Set the `Calendar` on the formatter and set a time zone on the `Calendar`.

Comment: FYI… Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Comment: I added a `Calendar` and did the time zone but no luck. `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
         cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-5"));
         formatter.setCalendar(cal);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help. I found out what my issue was. I implemented the class on the wrong section/order of the code. This works only when ‘deserializing’ object. So the code should look like this.

```
public class Feature implements Serializable {
private String dueDate;
@JsonDeserialize(using = DateAdaptor.class)
public Date getDueDate() {
    return due_date;
}
@JsonProperty("due_date")
public void setDueDate(Date dueDate) {
    this.due_date = dueDate;
}
```